# useEffect dependency doens't work unless I reload the screen

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I create these two useEffect.

as you can see first useEffect doesn't have any dependency.

so It will be executed at once.

at that time, I update `setCommunityList`.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (communityData !== undefined && communityData !== null) {
      setCommunityList(
        communityData.seeAllCommunities.map((community, index) => {
          return {
            label: community.communityName,
            value: community.communityName,
          };
        })
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

I call data through mutation of gql

```
  const { data: communityData, loading: communityLoading } = useQuery(
    SEE_ALL_COMMUNITIES_QUERY
  );
```

so that I put `communityData !== undefined && communityData !== null`.

unless I put this, it throws me an error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
> communityData.seeAllCommunities)

And second useEffect is this below.

once `communityList` is updated by first useEffect.
I change `loading` state from false to true.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (communityList.length > 0) {
      setLoading(true);
    }
  }, [communityList]);
```

But when I print console, second useEffect isn't executed.

If I reload screen, then communityList is updated and loading state is changed.

But I need to click reload button.

What is the problem here?

Comment: You are saying on first load it is not working and after reload it starts working? Can you log `communityList`. Maybe the array `communityData.seeAllCommunities` length is 0?

Comment: This really needs a [mcve]. My guess is that the test `if (communityData !== undefined && communityData !== null) {` doesn't pass so `setCommunityList` doesn't get called, but there isn't enough information in the question to confirm that (add logging!) or tell why.

Comment: I add the reason why I put `if (communityData !== undefined && communityData !== null)`

Comment: That only supports my point. If you don't have the `if` then because `communityData` is `undefined` it errors and `setCommunityList` never gets run. If you **do** have the `if` then the test stops `setCommunityList` from ever running. In either case `setCommunityList` never runs, so `communityList` never changes, so the `useEffect` hook that depends on `communityList` never executes.

Comment: @Quentin now I understand! so I add communityData as dependency in my first useEffect and I got it run. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (communityData !== undefined && communityData !== null) {
      setCommunityList(
        communityData.seeAllCommunities.map((community, index) => {
          return {
            label: community.communityName,
            value: community.communityName,
          };
        })
      );

communityData.seeAllCommunities.length >0 && setLoading(true)  //add this line 
    }
  }, []);
```